# How to sort a file before redirecting it as an input to a bash script?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I want to have the second column sorted before using it. It is ok to apply sort-command between braces or is there another method of integrating it into a bash script.
I was thinking of sorting the file.txt at the begining of the script.What other simple ways of sorting before redirecting as an input exists?

```
while IFS=, read var1 var2
do
//code//
done<(sort -t"," -k 2 file.txt)
```

Answer (score 2):

`(` and `)` are parentheses rather than braces - which would be `{` and `}`

The `<(command)` construct is called *process substitution*, and is syntactically equivalent to a file. To make it syntactically equivalent to *redirection from* a file you need another `<` operator:

```
while IFS=, read var1 var2
do
//code//
done < <(sort -t"," -k 2 file.txt)
```

The other common way to sort then redirect would be a simple pipe:

```
sort -t"," -k 2 file.txt | while IFS=, read var1 var2
do
//code//
done
```

The latter is more portable (process substitution is not a POSIX requirement, and is not supported by `/bin/sh` for example).